# Capitalize First Letter Of Each Word except for URLs

Tags: php, regex, url

Can someone tell me please how to do this:

```
Input:

hello http://DOMAIN.com/asdakdjk.php?asd=231&adsj=23 u.s. nicely done!

Result:

Hello http://DOMAIN.com/asdakdjk.php?asd=231&adsj=23 U.S. Nicely Done!
```

Including words in separated by '.' if possible such as in U.S.

Thanks

Comment: for words separated with a space you can use ucwords function of php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

function capitalizeNonURLs($input)
{
    preg_match('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', $input, $matches);
    $url = $matches[1];

    $temp = ucwords($input);
    $output = str_ireplace($url, $url, $temp);

    return $output;
}

$str = "hello http://domain.com/asdakdjk.php?asd=231&adsj=23 u.s. nicely done!";
echo capitalizeNonURLs($str);
```

Keep in mind that this function does not handle abbreviations (it won't change usa to USA). Country codes can be handled in several different ways. One is to make a hashmap of country codes and replace them or use regular expression for that as well.

Answer (score -1):

To keep urls lower:

```
$strarray = explode(' ',$str);
for($i=0;$i<count($strarray))
{
if(substr($strarray[$i],0,4)!='http')
{
    $strarray[$i] = ucfirst($strarray[$i])
}
}

$new_str = implode('',$strarray);
```